# Databound TextBox not updating with Source

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have a custom Class that implements *INotifyPropertyChanged* as follows (extraneous and repeated properties removed):

```
 Public Class Map
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

        Private _wages As Decimal
        Property Wages As Decimal
            Get
                Return _wages
            End Get
            Set(value As Decimal)
                Debug.Print("Event Raised: " & _wages & " " & value)
                _wages = value
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Wages))
            End Set
        End Property

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
```

The Class is being Serialized/Deserialized correctly. When I load the XML file the TextBox that displays wages is not updating to reflect the Wages value.

I have the (Devexpress) TextBox DataBindings set with:

```
txtWages.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("EditValue", mymap, "Wages", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

When I load the file I can see the old and new value from Debug.Print:

> Event Raised: 0 13

However, *txtWages* stays as 0

I have read these answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623775/databound-textbox-doesnt-reflect-source-changes) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373828/databound-textbox-not-updating-unless-selected) and tried to look for ideas but I am out of ideas.

**EDIT:** It seems that if I populate the class with the Deserialized XML and then set the Bindings it works, but not when the bindings are set first. I would have thought it would work either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should provide name of the property to the `PropertyChangedEventArgs`

   ```
   RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Nameof(Wages))
   ```
2. You did not show, but obviously when you "load" file and deserialize class you create new instance of `Map` and set it to `mymap`. Where control's binding will still refer to the original instance and listen it's events.

Create "wrapper" viewmodel with property of type `Map` and raise property change event when you load file.

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Private _Map As Map
    Property Map As Map
        Get
            Return _Map
        End Get
        Set(value As Map)
            _Map = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Nameof(Wages))
        End Set
    End Property  
End Class
```

Then in the form do binding

```
Dim viewmodel = new ViewModel()
viewmodel.Map = DeserializeMap() ' Your deserialize logic
txtWages.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", 
                          viewmodel, 
                          "Map.Wages", 
                          False, 
                          DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
```

Comment: `MyMap` is declared before the `New` sub. The code to Deserialize is: `MyMap = BM.Utilities.FileHelper.Deserialize(Of Map)("Routes.xml")` surely thats the same instance?

Comment: Deserialization will create new instance of type `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

U have Error in code

PropertyChangedEventArgs need String  (Name of property)

so "Wages"

```
 RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Wages"))
```

Comment: I noticed that myself too. Even with passing the property name rather than the property value it won't update unless I set the binding after the class has been populated.

Comment: so use Property Set for Map object and when u populate new object u can easy rebind form control